# Marshaling/Uninstalling JSON to parse and return field

Tags: java, json, jackson, marshalling, unmarshalling

I need to Un-Marshall JSON which contains a password field but while unmarshalling i do not want to send the password field, I'm using jackson API for this, can anyone please suggest how to achieve that.

Comment: *"i do not want to send the password"*--Perform secure hashing and send a hash

Answer (score 0):

Got that, by annotating password setter method with `@JsonProperty(value = "password")` and getter method with `@JsonIgnore`.